# Sorting incoming text data file in C# by a range of the record

Tags: c#, sorting

I have a file coming in (for display in a textbox).

```
var lines = new []
{
    "123465.xxx.20150115",
    "123465.xxx.20150222",
    "999999.xxx.20150120",
};
```

I can't affect the sorted order I receive it in. However, I want to sort from column 12 to column 19, then column 1 thru 6 (by date then by number) - in reverse order.

Currently I call a DOS sort (.bat) on the file creating a new file, but there has to be a way to sort in C#.

I want to sort it in the textbox or load an array, sort it, then load the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var lines = new []
{
    "123465.xxx.20150115",
    "123465.xxx.20150222",
    "999999.xxx.20150120",
}; 

var sorted =
    lines
        .OrderByDescending(l => l.Substring(11, 8) + l.Substring(0, 6))
        .ToArray();
```

Since string indexing is `0`-based then `.Substring(11, 8)` gives you "column 12 to column 19" & `.Substring(0, 6)` gives you "column 1 thru 6".

I get this result:

[image: sorted]